# Can Microsoft Graph API be used with a desktop python script?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to use the Microsoft Graph API to send emails and edit excel documents from my works 355 environment.

I'm able to get into Active directory and register an app, but I'm unsure how to figure out authentication without having a webervice, azure hosting etc.

It seems that most authentication flows need a redirect URl to receive the token after sending the client id and secret.

Is there a way for me to authenticate from a python script sitting on a local Windows machine with no static IP?

Comment: You should upgrade your works, I believe 365 is out already.

Comment: Huh? Microsoft 365 is still a service.

Comment: So why use 355 then? ;^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client credentials flow doesn't require a redireturi there is a good sample of using the MSAL in phython https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/confidential_client_secret_sample.py

If you want to use delegate authentication the other way would be the device code flow https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-devicecodeflow

Another option is the native redirect you might want to look at something like https://pypi.org/project/msal-interactive-token-acquirer/